# Change Four to Nine in fewest steps

Tags: word, no-computers, word-ladder

> Change the word
>
> FOUR
>
> to the word
>
> NINE

by changing only one letter at a time. The change must result in a 4 letter word from the MW dictionary and cannot be an abbreviation,acronym, anagram or a proper name.

The answer should take **Seven or fewer steps**

I expect more than one answers but the fewest step answer is needed.

Please no programming.

Comment: Are you allowed to rearrange the letters?

Comment: @Deepthinker101 "no anagrams" so no you cannot re arrange.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

5 Steps

> FOUR FOUD FOND FIND FINE NINE

Definition of special words

> [FOUD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foud) as found in MW

Comment: This is optimal. It is impossible to do it in less as the minimum is 4 as all 4 letters are different, and changing any of the four to the corresponding one in nine does not give a valid word, +1

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil There might be equivalent answers using different words though!

Answer (score 3):

Another 6 steps:

> POUR, POUT, PONT, PINT, PINE, NINE

Comment: This is nice: while it’s not [the shortest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/101596), it’s (so far) the shortest one that avoids obscure words.  (PONT isn’t quite everyday, but it’s better-known than FOUD or TORR as used in other answers.)

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution in 6

> tour, torr, tore, tire, tine, nine

If you are allowed to rearrange the letters then in 5

> sour, sure, sire, sine, nine

Comment: I was also wondering about rearranging the letter order

Answer (score 0):

A seven step answer using all common words.

> tour tout tort tore tone none nine